# Why is my data binding to a computed function not working (using knockout.js and jade)?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, pug

I am using knockout.js in my codepen.io, with jade as my preprocessor.

My edit buttons are supposed to change the value in the first td to true, and the save changes is supposed to change the value of the first td back to false. Why isn't the binding working? It binds to it the first time, but isn't constantly listening for a change apparently. Why is it not? The function I call on click is a computed function, and the variable I am trying to change is an observable. Why isn't it working??

Heres a link to my code, which is on codepen

http://codepen.io/jkwest30/pen/bpYXYP

heres the code as well

**Jade**

```
.container
  .users.col-md-11.col-xs-12.table-responsive 
table.col-xs-12
  tr
    th Name
    th Username
    th

  tr
    td 
      input.form-control(data-bind="value:edit()" )
    td 
      input.form-control(value="jkwest30@gmail.com" )
    td
      button.btn.btn-info.col-xs-12(data-bind="click:editFunction()") Edit
  tr
    td 
      input.form-control(value="Jake" )
    td 
      input.form-control(value="jkwest30@gmail.com" )
    td
      button.btn.btn-info.col-xs-12(data-bind="click:editFunction()") Edit

button.save.btn.btn-success.col-xs-12.col-md-4.col-md-offset-4(data-bind="click:saveChanges()") Save All Changes
```

**Javascript**

```
var viewModel = (function(){
    function viewModel(){
        var self = this;
        this.name = ko.observable("knockout works!");
        this.edit = ko.observable(false);
        this.editFunction = ko.computed(function(){
            self.edit(true);
        }) 
        this.saveChanges = ko.computed(function(){
            self.edit(false);
        })
    }
    return viewModel;
})()

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel())
```

FYI if you are not familiar with jade,simply click on the "view compiled" button just above the jade code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`computed observables` are dependent on one or more other observables, and will `automatically` `(not by click event)` update whenever any of these dependencies change. 
if you change your computed function to normal functions , they will be called whenever click event happens .
 Aside from that,make sure to structure your model in a way that you could bind `Edit` button to its row's input

```
 this.editFunction = function(){
   console.log("editFunction");
   self.edit(true);
 } 
 this.saveChanges = function(){
    console.log("saveChanges");
    self.edit(false);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of the edit button and its rows input, but I was just trying a bunch of different things and hadn't changed that yet. That makes perfect sense though, great answer! Easy points for you!